# Split a string with text and serverpaths into an array

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, split

my problem is, I have a string and I want to split it into an array. For example:

The string I get is

```
Unexpected Error: Check Availability of Data Source Failed:
\\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\_Folder\Folder_3\Folder\Folder\File_Fi_3.expression
 missing.
 \\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\_Folder\Folder_F6\Folder\Folder\File1_Fi_F2.expression
 missing. \\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Fo\Folder With
 Spaces\_Folder\Folder_F6\Folder\Folder\File123.expression missing.
 Details can be found on the Server at :
 \\server01\p.programming\Software
 Unit\01_Projects\Folder\Folder-FO-Fol\Folder\Folder_ErrorLog\Folder\Folder
 With Spaces\Log\
```

Now I will get an Array wich looks like this:

```
ArrayName[0] = "Unexpected Error: Check Availability of Data Source Failed: "
ArrayName[1] = "\\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\_Folder\Folder_3\Folder\Folder\File_Fi_3.expression"
ArrayName[2] = " missing."
ArrayName[3] = "\\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\_Folder\Folder_F6\Folder\Folder\File1_Fi_F2.expression"
ArrayName[4] = " missing."
ArrayName[5] = "\\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Fo\Folder With Spaces\_Folder\Folder_F6\Folder\Folder\File123.expression"
ArrayName[6] = " missing."
ArrayName[7] = "Details can be found on the Server at : "
ArrayName[8] = "\\server01\p.programming\Software Unit\01_Projects\Folder\Folder-FO-Fol\Folder\Folder_ErrorLog\Folder\Folder With Spaces\Log\"
```

I've tryed it to split by string.Split, but I get strings where the folder path includes spaces and the incoming string doesn't have everytime 4 serverpaths... It can be more or less. Maybe someone can help me :o)

Comment: what exactly do you want to be in splited array ?

Comment: did you try to split based on \r\n

Comment: It would be nice to have example of output you want to get

Comment: To Zeeshan: I want to get the serverpaths in own arrays, To Saddam: In my string aren't \n\r's To Aleksej: The output should look like the second code example which I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no new lines try to split by this regex `\\\\\w{1,}.*.expression\s missing`

Comment: Yes, but there are new lines. This is only an example message.. It can be between 1 and 30 lines.

Comment: can you add actuall data so i could give you the regex :) because you said that the string doesnt \r\n "which means new line". so if you have new lines you can split by \r\n and then for every field in the array get the match using the regex i included above

Comment: string message = @"Unexpected Error: Check Availability of Data Source Failed:\\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\_Folder\Folder_3\Folder\Folder\File_Fi_3.expression
 missing.\\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\_Folder\Folder_F6\Folder\Folder\File1_Fi_F2.expression missing. \\server01\z.storage\Folder\Folder\Fo\Folder With Spaces\_Folder\Folder_F6\Folder\Folder\File123.expression missing. Details can be found on the Server at : \\server01\p.programming\Software
 Unit\01_Projects\Folder\Folder-FO-Fol\Folder\Folder_ErrorLog\Folder\Folder With Spaces\Log\"